# Why do those terms vanish if the metric is Hermitian?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

On this [page](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=sfUICAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=we%20now%20define%20a%20hermitian%20manifold%20as%20a%20complex%20manifold%20where%20there%20is%20preferred%20class%20of%20coordinate&source=bl&ots=lS_eMIl13j&sig=arjL5QBrRexp5382VbyltH6_C5U&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdmIHI0dfJAhVBUhoKHQJ_AbwQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=we%20now%20define%20a%20hermitian%20manifold%20as%20a%20complex%20manifold%20where%20there%20is%20preferred%20class%20of%20coordinate&f=false), the author says:

> We now define a Hermitian manifold as a complex manifold where there is a preferred class of coordinate systems in which unmixed components of metric tensor vanish ($g_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}}=0$).

My question is why do those vanish if the metric is Hermitian?

Answer (score 3):

Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric which is hermitian with respect to an almost complex structure $J$, i.e. $g(JX, JY) = g(X, Y)$ for all vector fields $X$ and $Y$. Then we have

$$g_{\alpha\beta} = g(\partial_{\alpha}, \partial_{\beta}) = g(J\partial_{\alpha}, J\partial_{\beta}) = g(i\partial_{\alpha}, i\partial_{\beta}) = -g(\partial_{\alpha}, \partial_{\beta})= - g_{\alpha\beta} \implies g_{\alpha\beta} = 0,$$

and

$$g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}} = g(\bar{\partial}_a, \bar{\partial}_b) = g(J\bar{\partial}_a, J\bar{\partial}_b) = g(-i\bar{\partial}_a, -i\bar{\partial}_b) = -g(\bar{\partial}_a, \bar{\partial}_b) = - g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}} \implies g_{\bar{\alpha}\bar{\beta}} = 0.$$